# How to split text in longtable

Tags: longtable, split

Why is not the text in the table below split automatically? I use the environment `longtable` but the text is not split into two pages but I get the picture below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}  %\toprule
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ wasysym } % symbols
\usepackage{ amssymb } % symbols
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{ textcomp }

%----
\newcommand*{\fone}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont} % Eng word
\newcommand*{\ftwo}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont} % pronunciation
\newcommand*{\fthree}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont} %
\newcommand*{\ffour}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont} % 

\newcommand*{\UK}{{\small (UK) }}
\newcommand*{\sth}{\textit{\footnotesize sth }}
\newcommand*{\stb}{\textit{\footnotesize sb }}
\newcommand*{\frm}{\textit{\small (formal)} }
\newcommand*{\spee}{\textit{\small [+speech]} } 
\newcommand*{\frrm}{\textit{\small (rather formal)} }
\newcommand*{\ifrm}{\textit{\small (informal)} }
\newcommand*{\diss}{\textit{\small (disapproving)} }
\newcommand*{\odi}{\textit{\small (often disapproving)} }

\newcommand*{\tm}{\small \fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont} % komentar
\newcommand*{\tl}{\footnotesize \fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont} % str
\newcommand*{\slv}{\small \fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont} %pcr

%----

\newcommand*{\knihaB}{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaA}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaC}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaM}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihaEa}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaEb}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihacc}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaaa}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihabb}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy
\clearpage


{\large

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  {\knihaA to kneel} & {\knihaA knelt} & {\knihaA knelt} \\
  {\knihaB [\textipa{ni:l}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{nelt}]} & {\knihaB 
  [\textipa{nelt}]} \\ 
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{p{6cm}}{kľačať, pokľaknúť $\ataribox$ pokľaknúť (si),  kľaknúť si \textit{\small ({\knihaA down})}
  }\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  {\knihaA to know} & {\knihaA  knew} & {\knihaA known} \\
  {\knihaB [\textipa{n@U}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{nju:}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{n@Un}]} \\  
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{p{6cm}}{vedieť, poznať \textit{\small čo (naučené, vypočuté)} $\ataribox$ vedieť \textit{\small ({\knihaA of/about}) o čom}
  $\ataribox$ {\small {\knihaA get to know \textit{sb}} spoznať \textit{koho}} 
  $\ataribox$ vedieť, ovládať \textit{\small (jazyk)}; {\small {\knihaA I know how to speak \textit{language}}}
  }\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  {\knihaA to lay} & {\knihaA laid} & {\knihaA laid} \\
  {\knihaB [\textipa{leI}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{leId}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{leId}]} \\  
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{p{6cm}}{položiť, uložiť, klásť {\small (jemne, opatrne)} 
  $\ataribox$ klásť, položiť {\small \textit{({\knihaA down})}} 
  \textit{\small (koberec, potrubie ap. - na podlahu)} $\ataribox$ 
  rozprestrieť, rozložiť {\small \textit{čo ({\knihaA on/ over}) kde/ kam 
  (na podlahu ap.)}}; pokryť, zakriť {\small \textit{čo ({\knihaA with}) čím 
  (podlahu novinami ap.)}} $\ataribox$ zniesť, znášať \textit{\small 
  (vajcia)}$\ataribox$ {\small {\knihaA lay the table} \UK pripraviť stôl} 
  $\ataribox$\textit{\small (slang)} kefovať, trtkať \textit{\small koho 
  (súložiť)} $\ataribox$ {\small {\knihaA laying} {\knihaB 
  [\textipa{\textprimstress leIIN}]}} \newline $\ataribox$ 
  {\small {\knihaA to lie} {\knihaB [\textipa{laI}]} {\knihaA lay} {\knihaB 
  [\textipa{leI}]} {\knihaA lain} {\knihaB [\textipa{leIn}]} } {\small ležať 
  \textit{(zviera, človek, vec - v horozontálnej polohe)}; ležať, nachádzať 
  sa\textit{kde (mesto ap.)}; spočívať \textit{({\knihaA in}) v čom (problém 
  ap.)} }
  }\\
\end{longtable}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phfh1.png) when I run your example (pdftex in texlive 2017)

Comment: longtable can only split between rows it can not split a `\parbox` that is in a cell in its content.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it is correct. I want to have some text under the line on one page and the rest of text on another page.

Comment: in that case just set it as text at the top level (not inside longtable) so it can break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like your "long table" be less wide than a normal text line of the rest of your document, you could use `adjustwidth` from `changepage` package and a `tabularx` for the lines with the paradigms:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}  %\toprule
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ wasysym } % symbols
\usepackage{ amssymb } % symbols
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{ textcomp }

%----
\newcommand*{\fone}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont} % Eng word
\newcommand*{\ftwo}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont} % pronunciation
\newcommand*{\fthree}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont} %
\newcommand*{\ffour}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont} % 

\newcommand*{\UK}{{\small (UK) }}
\newcommand*{\sth}{\textit{\footnotesize sth }}
\newcommand*{\stb}{\textit{\footnotesize sb }}
\newcommand*{\frm}{\textit{\small (formal)} }
\newcommand*{\spee}{\textit{\small [+speech]} } 
\newcommand*{\frrm}{\textit{\small (rather formal)} }
\newcommand*{\ifrm}{\textit{\small (informal)} }
\newcommand*{\diss}{\textit{\small (disapproving)} }
\newcommand*{\odi}{\textit{\small (often disapproving)} }

\newcommand*{\tm}{\small \fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont} % komentar
\newcommand*{\tl}{\footnotesize \fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont} % str
\newcommand*{\slv}{\small \fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont} %pcr

%----

\newcommand*{\knihaB}{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaA}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaC}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaM}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihaEa}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaEb}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihacc}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaaa}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihabb}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
    \catcode`\-=12
    \sloppy
    \clearpage

    {\large\noindent
        \begin{adjustwidth}{1.2cm}{1.2cm}
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CCC}
                {\knihaA to kneel} & {\knihaA knelt} & {\knihaA knelt} \\
                {\knihaB [\textipa{ni:l}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{nelt}]} & {\knihaB 
                    [\textipa{nelt}]} \\ 
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}

            \noindent kľačať, pokľaknúť $\ataribox$ pokľaknúť (si),  kľaknúť si \textit{\small ({\knihaA down})}

            \noindent\newline
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CCC}
                {\knihaA to know} & {\knihaA  knew} & {\knihaA known} \\
                {\knihaB [\textipa{n@U}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{nju:}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{n@Un}]} \\  
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}

            \noindent vedieť, poznať \textit{\small čo (naučené, vypočuté)} $\ataribox$ vedieť \textit{\small ({\knihaA of/about}) o čom}
            $\ataribox$ {\small {\knihaA get to know \textit{sb}} spoznať \textit{koho}} 
            $\ataribox$ vedieť, ovládať \textit{\small (jazyk)}; {\small {\knihaA I know how to speak \textit{language}}}   

            \noindent\newline
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CCC}
                {\knihaA to lay} & {\knihaA laid} & {\knihaA laid} \\
                {\knihaB [\textipa{leI}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{leId}]} & {\knihaB [\textipa{leId}]} \\  
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}

            \noindent položiť, uložiť, klásť {\small (jemne, opatrne)} 
            $\ataribox$ klásť, položiť {\small \textit{({\knihaA down})}} 
            \textit{\small (koberec, potrubie ap. - na podlahu)} $\ataribox$ 
            rozprestrieť, rozložiť {\small \textit{čo ({\knihaA on/ over}) kde/ kam 
                    (na podlahu ap.)}}; pokryť, zakriť {\small \textit{čo ({\knihaA with}) čím 
                    (podlahu novinami ap.)}} $\ataribox$ zniesť, znášať \textit{\small 
                (vajcia)}$\ataribox$ {\small {\knihaA lay the table} \UK pripraviť stôl} 
            $\ataribox$\textit{\small (slang)} kefovať, trtkať \textit{\small koho 
                (súložiť)} $\ataribox$ {\small {\knihaA laying} {\knihaB 
                    [\textipa{\textprimstress leIIN}]}} \newline $\ataribox$ 
            {\small {\knihaA to lie} {\knihaB [\textipa{laI}]} {\knihaA lay} {\knihaB 
                    [\textipa{leI}]} {\knihaA lain} {\knihaB [\textipa{leIn}]} } {\small ležať 
                \textit{(zviera, človek, vec - v horozontálnej polohe)}; ležať, nachádzať 
                sa\textit{kde (mesto ap.)}; spočívať \textit{({\knihaA in}) v čom (problém 
                    ap.)}}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }
\end{document}
```

First page:
[image]

Second page:
[image]